# How to safeguard marketable ideas from being stolen?

Tags: funding, plagiarism, legal-issues, patents

Say I plan to share an idea with a professor that has the potential to inspire a biotech startup. **What forward-looking steps can I, as an undergraduate, take beforehand to ensure the professor won't poach the idea and pretend I never spoke with them?** Assume that the quality of the idea merits this much caution.

I'm frustrated by the fact that I hold seemingly zero leverage in this situation. The only way I can bring my idea into fruition is with a professor's resources. Can anyone give me ideas on how to properly safeguard my idea instead of praying my professor won't screw me over?

Would any of the following help: emailing my ideas to myself before the conversation, talking to my university's entrepreneurial/patent office (our ombudsperson department is somewhat lacking), sharing my ideas with other professors...

(The professor in question has an entrepreneurial flair and successfully founded + sold a few drug companies in the past. While most people say this professor is great, a small minority have also said that they have a bad side. Not sure who to believe.)

Comment: Related: [Is it appropriate for an undergrad student to ask a professor to sign a non-disclosure agreement?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/62646/4140)

Comment: Various answers-in-comments and other extended discussion has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134162/discussion-on-question-by-theheroncallsthroaway342-how-to-safeguard-marketable-i).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The current answers all suggest either completely dismissing any caution, or else a very high level of mistrust.  I’d suggest instead a middle ground: **You probably don’t need to worry, and you shouldn’t let this concern get in the way of your discussions with the professor; but there are some easy low-cost precautions that you can take to set your mind at rest.**

For the first side: Theft of ideas is rare (in all the fields I know), but it does sometimes happen.  Similarly, undergraduates coming up with ideas remarkable enough to be worth stealing by experts is unusual, but not unheard-of.  (Not to suggest your idea is worthless; the point is that most experts’ limiting factor is not ideas but the time/resources to develop them, and it’s unlikely that your idea is *better than all the others* the expert has to work on right now.)  So overall I think [Brunon’s answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/182193/1277) is right that you don’t need to worry much — but it’s not unnatural to have a bit of nagging worry about this, and want to set up a safety-net.

On the other hand, such theft is unlikely enough that I wouldn’t advise anything that’d slow your development of the ideas, either by requiring a lot of extra work, or by inhibiting fruitful mentoring and collaboration.  *Many* more good ideas get lost from demotivation or lack of support than from theft!  (In particular, I think the suggestions in [subassembly’s](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/182194/1277) and [Allure’s](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/182202/1277) answers sound counterproductive to me.)

But one simple thing that gives a bit of protection, at low-cost: **Describe your idea+plans casually to a few friends/fellow-students, including in writing (eg by email).**  This might not be enough to hold up priority in a court of law — but a lawsuit situation is *vanishingly* rare. The still-rare but slightly more likely scenario is that if anyone later seems to be “stealing” the idea, you can approach them, say “I brought this idea to you; X, Y, and Z can back me up.”, and ask to be included as a collaborator.  You can present it with an assumption of good faith, that they’re under-appreciating your contribution not deliberately erasing it — whether this is true or not, it gives them a face-saving way to acknowledge your contribution and bring you back on board, which is the best-case scenario for everyone.

To reiterate, I think that sort of situation is *rare* — but discussing your idea with multiple people doesn’t hurt at all anyway, gives a safety net for the rare chance of theft, and (most importantly) may help set your mind at rest and let you have more fruitful, less inhibited discussions with the professor.

Comment: If this becomes a matter of patent law, then those emails could well be prior art, and the idea is unpatentable (in the UK at least, not sure how international these rules are).

Comment: @Clumsycat: The recommendation of sending emails didn't seem to include any *public disclosure*.

Comment: @BenVoigt be careful with such amateur legal analysis. What is considered public disclosure according to a layperson is different from what is considered public disclosure according to patent law. I believe I read about a case when a public was deemed invalid because it was established that the inventor told about the idea to someone at a party before filing for a patent.

Answer (score 55):

Answer is, you don't. I am sorry to burst your bubble, but ideas themselves aren't worth anything. Not even a broken 0.01$ coin. It is the successful execution of those ideas that is actually valuable.

Thinking that you, as an undergraduate, have come with some flawless million-dollar-idea that an experienced academic -- a professor, no more no less -- is potentially going to "steal", is quite naïve to be honest. It sounds like a Dunning-Kruger effect talking. Even the best ideas aren't flawless and you need other people to take part in the process of development to average out all the subjective biases and you need their help in pointing out the flaws that you yourself cannot see. Let's take the invention of an integrated circuit as an example: it was invented and developed by hundreds of different people who contributed in various areas over a long period. It is not like it was invented by some isolated dude in the basement who just happened to go from 0 to 100% progress himself and then graced the whole world with his miraculous result. Just go talk with the professor, present your idea, listen to criticism, and enjoy your cooperation.

Comment: This is precisely why I said "Assume that the quality of the idea merits this much caution." My idea might be completely awful. In fact, statistically, I know it's practically guaranteed to be awful. I completely agree with that. But that doesn't mean that I shouldn't at least think about creating a safety net. I'm acting from a position of prudent caution, not neuroticism.

Comment: @theheroncallsthroaway342 Hey, I am sorry I didn't fully understand the question according to your intention, I am thinking about how to improve my answer and include those missing details you mentioned, thanks for responding to me.

Comment: And be humbly ready to learn why your idea isn't as great as you currently think it is. If you are, you'll learn and be better for it. Trust me, I have gone down a similar road ("I have a blockbuster idea!!") SO many times before. As @BrunonAlabamis points out, innovation is done by a lot of people working very hard together--or occasionally one person working very VERY hard by themselves **who is an expert in the field**. A lone novice is not in a position to innovate unless they get really really lucky (and not a gamble worth trying). Your best bet is to focus on learning...

Comment: ...while keeping up the creative spirit. So do think up new ideas, but don't hold them up to yourself as grand inventions--hold them as fun ideas to prompt you to go off and learn more. Eventually if you keep it up you'll have actual expertise and will have a reasonable hope of innovating. But as novice you're not there. And when you do get there, you'll have to **work really hard refining your idea, likely in collaboration**. The initial idea is very unlikely to survive intact, even in that scenario. In short, most ideas stink, but they can have valuable great-great-great-great grandchildren.

Comment: @theheroncallsthroaway342 the thing about your “assume that the quality of the idea merits this much caution” condition is that you’re asking us to assume something that is not realistic or believable. This answer is a frame challenge, confronting you with the lack of realism of your assumptions. No one is accusing you of neuroticism, but this answer is good because it explains why allowing yourself to be paralyzed by “prudent caution” is counterproductive.

Comment: @DanRomik I disagree with the dismissal of the possibility that the idea could have some merit to it. Even if the guy is the leading expert in the field, he might have blind spots. The past decade in particular was very fruitful with applying math and IT to basically everything; old-timers know a lot but often happen to be unable to execute on some things, which is where the students could seize the opportunity for a career boost... The answer is still applicable though: even if the idea might be crucial for a project, the managerial/resource procuring side is by far more important.

Comment: @theheroncallsthroaway342 Even under your premise, this is still the correct answer. "I have this awesome idea but can't execute on it. How can I protect it from the people who could actually execute on it?" is a common problem also outside the academic world. There isn't really a fix for it, and this is part of why an idea without execution isn't valuable.

Answer (score 6):

As with other considerations re plagiarism, you establish precedence. Set up some kind of paper trail with verifiable time stamps to show that you came up with the idea first, before you talked to the professor. You could for example write your idea on a piece of paper in grand detail, and bring it to a lawyer or justice of the peace and get them to certify it. It probably won't be free, of course, but we are assuming the quality of the idea merits this much caution.

Then if the professor steals your idea, you file a plagiarism complaint with their department using your paper trail as evidence.

Comment: Plagiarism requires that another's work is *claimed as your own*. Starting a company based on someone else's idea isn't plagiarism if you credit them with the idea. A university might not look kindly on a professor that cuts students out of their own ideas, but I don't think plagiarism describes the situation well, nor does it give any legal protection to the idea anyway. A simple citation eliminates any possibility of plagiarism.

Comment: If the aim is just to prove when you had the idea, why not just put an encrypted file on a github repo? The world can see when you uploaded it, but cannot read it without the key.

Comment: I gotta agree with @NuclearHoagie here, making a case for plagiarism would probably not be an effective way to prevent someone else from starting a company with your idea. Patenting is the right tool for the job. Unfortunately, getting a patent is a much more involved process than establishing precedence, but that gets into legal issues that would probably be off topic here.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an idea **worth stealing**, it should also be **worth publishing**. Go ahead and write an article about it, then submit it to a couple of journals for review. Such submissions, even rejected ones, will have a much higher value for establishing precedence than e-mails sent to yourself or conversations with colleagues.

If you get your article published (which is not so hard if you consider second-rank journals), it will clearly establish your precedence as the author of the idea.

If your idea is something extremely generic and vague, e.g. "build a quantum computer to mine bitcoin" without any implementation details, you won't be able to publish it (except in a predatory journal), however, nobody can "steal" it either because there's literally nothing to steal.

Note that publishing your idea makes it impossible to patent, which means a publication will prevent your supervisor from turning the idea into a startup behind your back, but it will also prevent you from doing so yourself. If you want to exploit the idea commercially, you need to patent it **before** publishing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to accomplish the OP's goal - they're trying to make it so the professor can't use the idea without their involvement. Publication makes the idea available so that *anyone* can use the idea without the OP's involvement. This ensures the OP gets the credit for having the idea first, but doesn't protect the idea in any way.

Answer (score 2):

''The only way I can bring my idea into fruition is with a professor's resources.''

It sounds like you have answered your own question.  You are not able to carry out the idea without the professor, so sounds like you don't have much of a choice in the matter.  Just having ''raw ideas'' is maybe not as important as you think it is right now.  You'll see as you progress further in your career that these raw ideas generally have to be ''minted'' and turned into something tangible ie. you have to get some actual new results or do something new with the idea.

It sounds to me like you need this professor's assistance to get this idea minted, so I'm not sure what choice you have in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Before you speak to your professor sit down using, e.g. Google Scholar, and look deep and wide into the available literature. You might need some time to get used to the particular language in your field. After that review it is guaranteed that your idea is now on a more solid foundation.

If in this research you did not discover that someone else described something very similar to your idea or concept then play your own devil's advocate: "Why is this idea not working out?"

If you then conclude that your idea has a somewhat unique touch and potential go to your professors (plural!) and ask them why this might not work out. You do not have to specify every little detail here, a rough sketch is fine.

Now you have a lot of input to refine your idea. At this point you have to ask yourself about how to realize your much refined concept. This could be a patent, a publication or a biotech startup. Each have their benefits and disadvantages, now you have not yet really revealed your idea to the world and all the paths are open for you.

The only sad choice would be to let it sit in a drawer and collect dust because you think someone else will steal it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, ideas are common and generally worthless without execution — that’s where the value is. So, with that in mind, I’d like to present some thoughts that may help you be comfortable sharing your idea and understand what some of risks and benefits may be:

1. Fear around having an idea stolen is typically based on a fear of *losing an opportunity* to realize some large, but *fundamentally abstract*, future benefit. Most people think of this benefit in terms of money. But the reality is if point A is the idea, point B is almost certainly not money — rather, it’s probably the conversation that in you’re case you have anxiety around.
2. Some people are exploitative in nature, but it’s generally rare and in business almost always opportunistic. For example, think about the well-known saga of Mark Zuckerberg, the Winklevoss twins, and the founding of Facebook. The twins were exploited, but the only reason that was possible is because Zuckerberg had two things, at least one of which they lacked: *time* and *expertise*. Sure, your professor has the expertise, but there’s a very good chance he doesn’t have the time to launch a new venture. Time to give you advice? That’s a much more probable. And, from a purely cynical business perspective, providing advice will still keep him in a position to extricate value from any successful company that results — not that that’s necessarily a bad thing! Maybe he’ll want to be a scientific advisor, on the board, or a chief scientific officer (though that last one’s a much bigger commitment!)
3. As a general principle, especially as an undergrad (I’m assuming you’re in your late teens or early 20s), I’d recommend having faith in the process. When you’re young, the thing you often lack and the greatest value you can extricate from something like this is probably *experience*. Experience working closely on an idea with faculty, experience selling an idea, experience developing a vision, experience trying to launch a company, experience developing a novel technology. Some of these things may directly result in a great financial benefit in the future, but what’s certain is that no matter what happens after you share your idea, it will almost undoubtedly be a learning experience. And you’ll almost certainly have another brilliant idea after it. And when that happens, you’ll have more experience to leverage — and possibly relationships (e.g. with investors) and other contacts too.
4. Finally, you can test the waters before sharing it fully. For example, ask the professor: “Hypothetically, if a student came to you with an idea for a technology/business you found compelling, would you have the bandwidth to pursue it? What would you see your role as? Have you had it happen before? Was it successful?” Those types of conversations will likely help you gauge whether this professor is the right person to share it with.

One final (and very important!) point: **Talk to the tech transfer office at your university before sharing your idea.** It may be that once you bring the professor in on it (and you can ask them this too) that the university now owns the IP because he’s an employee of the university. You may also be subject to an IP agreement as a student, too. Here are a few common reasons IP ends up being owned by the university. 1. It’s something the professor worked on/provided guidance for in an official capacity, 2. University resources were used to develop it (e.g. lab equipment or a university owned laptop), or 3. You signed an IP agreement when you joined the university that gave them rights to any intellectual property you develop as a student. Not all universities are so onerous with their IP, but some are. Be mindful of that.

Answer (score -2):

This is a very real and important threat. The way my PhD supervisor taught me to guard against it is to always withhold an important piece of information that is required in completing it independently. Don't give people your working or your Mathematica notebooks etc. Always consciously leave a few things out that are required to actually realise the project. Hope this helps

EDIT: our group leader always said to be careful who you tell, if you tell a postdoc from MIT your interesting idea it will take you 3 years as a new student but they can do it in a few months

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: IMO if you describe your calculation method to your professor and withhold the the Mathematica notebook, recreating it shouldn't take more than a couple of days.

Answer (score -2):

I am very new to this and have never done this myself, but you can save your idea in a document and then **store a hash value of that document on a blockchain**, e.g. Ethereum. That transaction will have a time-stamp, and in addition only you will be able to provide the document that produces the stored hash, which should suffice to prove you are the owner of the idea.

You can try to start with [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/how-can-i-store-data-in-ethereum-blockchain) on the Ethereum StackExchange site, or find your own way to how and on which blockchain to do that.

Comment: This is worth doing, in my opinion, but it's important to state that it does not provide any legal protection. (*That* would require a patent or contract.) It could help someone prove that they had the idea first and get the recognition for it and embarrass anyone who stole it.
There are other ways of achieving this, such as timestamping services (e.g. digistamp.com) (the signed stamp received can be held by both the IP owner and the service). (I'm NOT the downvoter.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info an clarification.